# how to create a function which takes 2 vectors as arguments

Tags: matlab, vector

The function shall return the numbers in the 1st vector that is greater than the largest value in the 2nd vector.

For example : If the 2 vectors are: `[4,34,7,63,16]` & `[2,9,8,7,3,10,16,1]` the function should return the vector `[34,63]`.

Comment: And your question is...?

Comment: you need to specify, at leat, in what language are you facing the problem, and state it via tags.

Answer (score 2):

This is a very simple function so I'd usually use an anonymous function for that:

```
>> x=[4,34,7,63,16];
>> y=[2,9,8,7,3,10,16,1];
>> yourFunction = @(x,y)x(x > max(y));
>> yourFunction(x,y)

ans =

    34    63
```

if you need it in a function file you'd use this:

```
function m = yourFunction(x,y)
m=x(x > max(y));
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the matlab documentation e.g. 
http://www.mathworks.de/de/help/matlab/ref/function.html
There you also find examples. In your case you just have to enter 2 arguments on the right side of the definition. 
An example for a function with 2 arguments would be:

```
function[returnval] = value(time, frequency)
  pi = 3.1415926536;
  returnval= sin(2*pi*frequency*time);
end
```

This function would have the name value which expects 2 arguments and returns 1 argument.

Obviously you have to define your function differently but the question wasn't about your code but how to create a function with 2 input arguments.